# Read complex text file using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file

File Structure

```
RECORD
1234567890,123456789,1234567,Address1,,City,State,Zip,USA,Phone,,,,,,,,,
EmpName,DBAName,ID,,Address1,,Address1,City,60603,USA,234567890,,,,
C,03/13/2017,,1,2,
RECORD
1234567890,123456789,1234567,Address1,,City,State,Zip,USA,Phone,,,,,,,,,
EmpName2,DBAName2,ID2,,Address2,,Address2,City2,60603,USA,234567890,,,,
C,03/13/2017,,1,2,
```

Looking at the above file structure, I want to loop through file and for each record(RECORD), I want to put next three lines in one array and then next record in separate array.

I am looking for skeleton code, I am very new in programming using stream readers.

Code so far

```
 Dim read As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\New Text.txt")
       Dim a As String

       For Each a In read.ReadLine
           If read.ReadLine.Equals("RECORD") Then
               \\How do I read next 3 lines and put them in one array with comma delimiter
           End If
       Next
```

Comment: I would look up the `string.Split()` function along with the `File.ReadAllText()` this is actually not that difficult. There are plenty of working examples even on this page itself `VB.NET Read Certain text in a text file` the 5th link under `Related`

Comment: just do it. read the next 3 lines (ReadLine), then concat the 3 string you get.

Comment: @pm100 Can you please tell me how to only read next three lines?
And then how to put them in an array. I will appreciate if you can write some code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a data structure where you will keep the lines loaded and then start your loop

```
' Here you will keep the 3 lines block joined together and splitted on comma
Dim records = new List(Of String())()

Using read As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\New Text.txt")
   Dim a As String

   ' Read each line (Assuming that we start with a RECORD line
   For Each a In read.ReadLine
       ' Do not read another line, but just test what is present in the string
       If a.Equals("RECORD") Then

          ' Now read the 3 following lines....
          Dim line1 = read.ReadLine
          Dim line2 = read.ReadLine
          Dim line3 = read.ReadLine
          'Join the lines togeter
          Dim record = string.Join("", line1, line2, line3).
          ' Split on the comma to produce an array of strings. The fields.
          Dim fields = record.Split(","c)
          records.Add(fields)
       End If
   Next
End Using
```

Of course this should be enhanced using a proper class that describe your inputs where each property of the class represent a field of the CSV file loaded. And then you could change the List(Of String()) to a List(Of YourClassData)

Keep in mind that this solution is extremely dependant of an exact file structure. A line with the "RECORD" content should be always followed by three lines of data. (No blank lines allowed between the three data lines)

Answer (score -1):

```
     Dim read As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\New Text.txt")
//I usually only do C#, but rough VB.NEt code: I did not rcreate your array for you, figured you got that :-)
       Dim a As String
       Dim myConcatString as String
       For Each a In read.ReadLine
          Dim myReadLine as String 
            myReadLine = read.ReadLine
           If myReadLine.Equals("RECORD") Then
myConcatString = myConcatString  & myReadLine 
               \\How do I read next 3 lines and put them in one array with comma delimiter
           else
           //add myConcatString to array if not null....
myConcatString =""
           End If
       Next
```

Comment: I did not hard-code the "three" lines, as your really breaking on each occurrence of "RECORD"